# I think my server was hacked - how do i know what has been changed?

Tags: ubuntu, security, firewall, hacking, ubuntu-13.04

I have read the following posts which didn't answered my questions:
- [My linux server was hacked. How do I find out how and when it was done?](https://serverfault.com/questions/208782/my-linux-server-was-hacked-how-do-i-find-out-how-and-when-it-was-done)
- [How do I know if my Linux server has been hacked?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2783/how-do-i-know-if-my-linux-server-has-been-hacked)
- and much more...

**The server setup was this:**
- the Ubuntu server was after a router (Cisco EA6500) and didn't had port forward (uPNP is enabled).
- the stupidest idea was to have a user called `user` with password `user`.

Today I entered on the php webeditor which connects by ssh and didn't accepted the password. I found out that the server might have been hacked.

**I found the followings:**
- **all** the server files timestamps are changed to my last login date (today)
- there was one cronjob `/dev/shm/-   /.ICE-UNIX/update >/dev/null 2>&1` [added friday](http://pastebin.com/rsuHURg8)
- there was an error on ubuntu start-up that said "error variable ROOT isn't set"

**What I did:**
- recover password by recovery console
- setting up a [small firewall](http://pastebin.com/QMRtchjF) which got [some attempts](http://pastebin.com/WPrfU1tk) to get into ssh.

**Questions:**
- How do i know what has been changed?
- How did they get in if there was no ssh port exposure?

> **Later Edit:**   They have left the logs intact and I found out that [they entered by ssh](http://pastebin.com/Pcm8bXa1) and changed the
>   password. There were a lot of ssh login tries over the past weeks. I
>   have reinstalled the system, moved the port, installed a firewall and
>   I'm inspectting the router. It definitely has security holes. Thank
>   you all!

Comment: If you have a backup, compare with that everything.

Comment: Really SvW? I already said I read ALL the articles on this subject from `Stack Exchange` websites, including that one you gave me.

Comment: @Peter Horvath: I ran a checksum check comparison with the backup files: `rsync --dry-run -v -r -c --delete directoryA/ directoryB/`, but nothing was changed.

Comment: Do it from a rescue disk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't trust that machine anymore, and would reinstall and probably scan for rootkits (some rootkits even survive formatting of a drive).

If you care about security, my personal advice would be to restart fresh.

Comment: Regarding your question - you really can't know what has been changed. Unless you have everything in a versioning system or manually compare it with a backup.

Comment: I guess I would have to do that. But I would like to know what has been changed, to know the security hole. That's very important.

Comment: Well, you mention the PHP/SSH-login thing, that's likely to be it. Usually these systems have a configuration file, like server.com/configuremystuff.php - attacks are often used against these, as they are well-known and often have security risks.

You also mention a very bad username/password, it is likely someone scanned the ports on your server and found a port with SSH active - you said you used some webeditor that connects through SSH, so some SSH port should be active?

Comment: SSH scans and brute force attacks are extremely common. I get attempts every day. Don't allow root logins, if you're in control of ssh settings.

Comment: but how did they get past the router? the ssh port isn't accesible fron WAN.

Comment: If that is the case, then through your webpage providing such access, I would guess.

Comment: Thank for your help. I have accepted your answer, even though it's not quite the answer to what I asked. However, you helped me ;)

Comment: Did you find the flaw? If it's through the web page, you would be able to find logs in /var/log/httpd-access, or the like.

Comment: i edited my question. you can see there how "they" got in.

Comment: "Some rootkits even survive formatting of a drive" [citation needed] - in the context of this discussion (a remote exploit), I do not believe this is currently possible. The only rootkits that can survive a complete reformat involve physical access to inject code into the BIOS, no?